# contao-manager console returns error when installing packages - contao 4.4.4

Tags: contao

Hi friends I installed contao 4.4.4 via contao manager . I have successfully completed the installation and get entered in backend . But when installing new packages the contao-manager console returns error. Why it happens??? Please provide me a solution to install extension modules.
[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information. Is there any indication of what kind of error happens?

Comment: I shared a screenshot now.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have much experience with the Contao Manager yet. I think there should be a log somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing via the terminal, composer install and name of package
2.Rebuild the cache
3.Go to install tool and update the database, so that if any package deleted or added, it needs to be updated